# Find the highest number after specific string from mutiple files

Tags: awk, grep, find, sort

Each file has similar content:

```
number 1:
asdfa11sdfsadf
number 2:
asdfa12sdfsadf
number 1:
asdfa1sdfsadf
number 3:
asdfa33sdfsadf
```

return

```
3 or number 3: are equally good.
```

Have tried:

```
max="$( awk -F":" 'BEGIN{max=0}{if(($2)>max)  max=$2}END {print max}' file)"
printf "%d\n" "$max"
```

it will return the 33 but not 3.

also have tried:

```
grep -o 'number\s[0-9]*' file1.txt file2.txt | sort -nr | head -1
```

it will return the highest based on the files input hierarchy(it will only find the highest number from file2, even if the highest number is in file1 as number 8:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your last command but use grep with `-ho` instead of `-o`:

`grep -ho 'number\s[0-9]*' file1.txt file2.txt | sort -nr | head -1`

`-h` will remove file name from the results which is causing the issue.

Comment: using this command, how can we find out where the highest number comes from, like which file? Thank you.

Comment: In that case you can sort based on the second column which contains the actual number as such:

`grep -o 'number\s[0-9]*' file1.txt file2.txt | sort -rk 2 | head -1`

But the result will include filename.

Comment: Yes. now the file name is included, but the result is not corrected.

Comment: I think we can run one addition command once we find the highest number.

Comment: Well, this is working fine for me:
`# grep -o 'number\s[0-9]*' file1.txt file2.txt | sort -rk 2 | head -1
file1.txt:number 8`